# Why isin does not filter rows Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Dataset is:

```
AGE NUM
18  1
19  2
20  3
6   4
```

The `invalidatedNumsDb` is filled from database:

```
def getWrongNumbersDb():
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT num FROM invalidated")
    return set([int(vl[0]) for vl in cursor.fetchall()])
invalidatedNumsDb = getWrongNumbersDb()
```

The `invalidatedNumsDb` contains numbers `{1,2,3}`

After I try to filter all rows where `NUM` is not presented in `invalidatedNumsDb`:

```
report = {}
report['num_file_dup'] = dataset.duplicated(subset=['NUM']).sum()
report['num_invalid'] = (~dataset['NUM'].apply(checkNumber)).sum()
report['num_dup_db'] = (dataset['NUM'].isin(invalidatedNumsDb)).sum()

dataset.drop_duplicates(subset="NUM")
filter1 = ~dataset['NUM'].isin(invalidatedNumsDb)
filter2 = dataset['AGE'].apply(isOld)

dataset = dataset[filter1 & filter2]
```

As result I want to get the same frame excluding rows that returns false in `filter1` and `filter2`.

But I always get full dataset despite `NUM` is presented in `{1,2,3}`

Result should be:

```
AGE NUM
6   4
```

I have tried to convert `NUM` column into int:

```
dataset = dataset.astype({'NUM':'int64'})
```

But has not effect, so problem in `isin` on the line:

```
filter1 = ~dataset['NUM'].isin(invalidatedNumsDb)
```

Comment: Are you doing `dataset.astype({'CCUNM':'int64'})` in your code or was it a typo? It should be `dataset.astype({'NUM':'int64'})`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.